# Taking only the maximum values of duplicate IDs for all columns of a data frame in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyr

I have data frame of 24525 rows and 22 columns. Last column is the ID column, other are numeric. Number of unique IDs is 18414 and some IDs are repeated more than 2 times.

I need to remove duplicate IDs and keep only the maximum value for each ID and each column in another data frame.

I tried sorting each column in a for loop and remove duplicates to keep the maximum but it did not work and I am not sure.

Is anyone knows a way to do this task?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is the maximum value in a specific column or the sum of all numerical columns?

Comment: The premise of *"sorting each column"* is anathema to the premise that a `data.frame` is organized into *observations* (rows) and *properties* (columns). By changing the order of values within a column, the correlation between observations (rows) is now broken. With some datasets this might be fine, but in general I think it suggests that `data.frame` is not the perfect/preferred data structure (if breaking the correlation is okay).

Answer (score 1):

Fake data:

```r
mt <- mtcars
mt$cyl <- as.character(mt$cyl)
```

### Base R

```r
aggregate(. ~ cyl, data = mt, FUN = max)
#   cyl  mpg  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1   4 33.9 146.7 113 4.93 3.190 22.90  1  1    5    2
# 2   6 21.4 258.0 175 3.92 3.460 20.22  1  1    5    6
# 3   8 19.2 472.0 335 4.22 5.424 18.00  0  1    5    8
```

(Thanks to @GregorThomas for the tweaks on this.)

### tidyverse

```r
library(dplyr)
mt %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarize_all(max)
# # A tibble: 3 x 11
#   cyl     mpg  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 4      33.9  147.   113  4.93  3.19  22.9     1     1     5     2
# 2 6      21.4  258    175  3.92  3.46  20.2     1     1     5     6
# 3 8      19.2  472    335  4.22  5.42  18       0     1     5     8
```

*Update*: as suggested by @akrun, `dplyr::summarize_all` has been superseded. From the [`?summarize_all`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise_all.html):

> Scoped verbs (`_if`, `_at`, `_all`) have been superseded by the use of `across()` in an existing verb. See `vignette("colwise")` for details.

Updated code:

```r
mt %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarize(across(everything(), max))
# # A tibble: 3 x 11
#   cyl     mpg  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 4      33.9  147.   113  4.93  3.19  22.9     1     1     5     2
# 2 6      21.4  258    175  3.92  3.46  20.2     1     1     5     6
# 3 8      19.2  472    335  4.22  5.42  18       0     1     5     8
```

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(mt)
mt[, lapply(.SD, max), by=.(cyl)]
```

Comment: Re-reading the question, I think you understood OP's intent better than me.

Comment: I could not come up with any use of `order` that satisfied the requirement for each column individually.

Comment: No, that would be terrible - ordering each column individually within groups isn't a fun job for base R when you can just do this.

Comment: Though as I write that comment you ninja-edit a really nice solution....

Comment: ᕦ(ò_óˇ)ᕤ (flexing muscles :-)

Comment: Ah, but the sorting is a red herring! Only good for my version (keeping a row, not max values from each column). The nice `base` answer is `aggregate(. ~ cyl, data = mt, FUN = max)`

Comment: You win ... I kept trying `aggregate(mt, . ~ cyl, FUN = max)`, S3 got me again.

Comment: (Are you going to take that one? If not, I'm adding it to my list :-)

Comment: Nah, I'll stick with my original interpretation of the Q, for better of for worse. Get rid of the `do.call` mess and take my `aggregate`.

Comment: It may be better to add `summarise(across(everything(), max))` as the other options are deprecated in dplyr